# code block in curly braces after the function call

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm looking over this code (stripped down version of the implementation of createStore within the Redux source code)

```
function createStore(reducer) {
    var state;
    var listeners = []

    function getState() {
        return state
    }

    function subscribe(listener) {
        listeners.push(listener)

        return unsubscribe() {
            var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
            listeners.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }

    function dispatch(action) {
        state = reducer(state, action)
        listeners.forEach(listener => listener())
    }

    dispatch({})

    return { dispatch, subscribe, getState }
}
```

My question is specific to the below block inside

```
function subscribe(listener)


return unsubscribe() {
   var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
   listeners.splice(index, 1)
}
```

The section in the curly bracket

```
{
   var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
   listeners.splice(index, 1)
}
```

does that block gets passed to the unsubscribe() method? any resemblance to Ruby's blocks? how does that work in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there are some issues with the code you posted. A better stripped-down version of the [`createStore()`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/createStore.js) function would be:

```
function createStore(reducer) {
  var listeners = [];

  function subscribe(listener) {
    listeners.push(listener);

    return function unsubscribe() {
      var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
      listeners.splice(index, 1)
    };
  }

  return {subscribe};
}
```

Note that <s>you were forgetting some semicolons and that</s> (*EDIT: the OP forgot nothing. Redux [skips semicolons to conform](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/741662198234271744) to React Router ESLint*) the `subscribe()` method wasn't returning `function unsubscribe()` but just `unsubscribe()`.

Now, answering the question, [this article](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2014/05/19/ruby-methods-arent-first-class-but-procs-are-first-class/) is a nice lecture to illustrate the differences between Ruby and JavaScript on this topic.

> Ruby methods are not functions or first-class citizens because they cannot be passed to other methods as arguments, returned by other methods, or assigned to variables. Ruby procs are first-class, similar to JavaScript’s first-class functions.

In JavaScript functions are truly first-class citizens. They can be passed a round as any other piece of data.

In our example, the `createStore()` function returns an object, containing the function/method `subscribe()`. It does so by returning the name of the function (`subscribe`). Likewise, `subscribe()` also returns a function, but this time the declaration of that function happens directly inside the `return` statement. Both are valid ways to pass a function.

When you instantiate`createStore` by a function call, you will obtain the returned object.

```
var myObject = createStore("foo");
```

The new object has the method `subscribe()`. If you call that method you will obtain the `unsubscribe()` function.

```
var myFunction = myObject.subscribe("bar");
```

Of course, you could do it in one line by:

```
var myFunction = createStore("foo").subscribe("bar");
```

Try it in the snippet below:

```js
function createStore(reducer) {
  var listeners = [];

  function subscribe(listener) {
    listeners.push(listener);

    return function unsubscribe() {
      var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
      listeners.splice(index, 1)
    };
  }

  return {subscribe};
}

var myObject = createStore("foo");
console.log(myObject);  // print an object with the subscribe method.
var myFunction = myObject.subscribe("bar");
console.log(myFunction);  // print the unsubscribe function

console.log(createStore("foo").subscribe("bar"));
```

You might also want to read about objects in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: True, adding the function keyword before unsubscribe made it clearer. I was referring to the code as used on this tutorial (https://medium.freecodecamp.org/understanding-redux-the-worlds-easiest-guide-to-beginning-redux-c695f45546f6)  and my bad didnt bother to refer the original code. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: The semicolons are optional (actually in the original code they are also missing, [Redux conforms to React Router ESLint config](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/741662198234271744)). So, actually, I shouldn't call it an issue (even when I really dislike it). But leaving out the `function` keyword is a typo in the tutorial you linked to: the code won't work without it.

Answer (score 2):

Whan you call `subscribe` and pass it a listener, it returns you a function which you can call anytime later. Ex:

```
const {dispatch, subscribe, getState} = createStore(this.myReducer); 
// for demonstration purpose. Now you have references to the values createStore() returns;

const subscription = this.subscribe(this.listener)
```

Now whenever you call `this.subscription()` it will execute this:

```
var index = listeners.indexOf(listener)
listeners.splice(index, 1)
```

with `listener` being saved in a closure.

Comment: Awww.. I was thinking unsubscribe() was an existing method :D.. looks like just naming a function block ?

Comment: Indeed. you forgot the `function` keyword :)

Answer (score 1):

That block of code is part of the `unsubscribe` function that is returned by the subscribe method

Answer (score 1):

It also took some time for me, to find the syntax definition for this, it is a shorthand object-method definition, as described here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

```
const obj = {
  foo: function () {
    // …
  },
  bar: function () {
    // …
  },
};
```

You are now able to shorten this to:

```
const obj = {
  foo() {
    // …
  },
  bar() {
    // …
  },
};
```